# How to get an associated field value at selected index using combo box in javascript while fetching JSON response

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, combobox, html-select

Hello i am developing a phone-gap app and fetching the data from WCF service which returns me JSON response.
I need to show DesignName in the combo box and pass the associated designId…Any idea how to do that?

This is the json response..

```
{
    "DesignResult":
    "{\"DesignId\":\"1\",\"DesignName\":\"Bedroom\"}     
     {\"DesignId\":\"2\",\"DesignName\":\"Dining\"}
     {\"DesignId\":\"5\",\"DesignName\":\"Entertainment\"}
     {\"DesignId\":\"4\",\"DesignName\":\"Occasional Tables\"}
     {\"DesignId\":\"6\",\"DesignName\":\"Office\"}
     {\"DesignId\":\"3\",\"DesignName\":\"Upholstery\"}"
}
```

this is the function with which i can get the text at selected position

```
var combo1 = document.getElementById("designBox");
var val = combo1.options[combo1.selectedIndex].text;
```

but this will give me DesignName as i need to show DesignName in the box but i need to get the associated DesignId..

With following code i am adding options dynamically

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Design.length; i++) 
{
opt = document.createElement("option");  
opt.text= jsonData.Design[i].DesignName;
sel = document.getElementById("designBox");  
sel.add(opt); 
}
```

modified the code as follows but getting "Null"for DesignId

```
var optElement = document.createElement("option");
optElement.setAttribute('value',jsonData.Design[i].DesignId);
optElement.innerHTML = jsonData.Design[i].DesignName;
```

to retrieve:

```
var combo1 = document.getElementById("designBox");
var test = combo1.getAttribute('value');
alert("test value is...."+test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in JSON.
Its syntactically incorrect. I've fixed that for you.

Read about and study JSON thoroughly [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

```
var jsonData = '{
    "DesignResult": [
        {
            "DesignId": "1",
            "DesignName": "Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "DesignId": "2",
            "DesignName": "Dining"
        },
        {
            "DesignId": "5",
            "DesignName": "Entertainment"
        },
        {
            "DesignId": "4",
            "DesignName": "OccasionalTables"
        },
        {
            "DesignId": "6",
            "DesignName": "Office"
        },
        {
            "DesignId": "3",
            "DesignName": "Upholstery"
        }
    ]
}';
```

This is a string returned from server. Now cast it into javascript JSON object using `eval()` function. like,

```
jsonData = eval('(' + jsonData + ')');
```

Now you are able to iterate over this JSON object using loops and all.
To access the data you need, you have to implement it like,

Try this

```
var len = jsonData.DesignResult.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
alert("Name - "+jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignName+" || ID - "+jsonData.DesignResult.DesignId);
}
```

To fix your code,

```
var len = jsonData.DesignResult.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
        opt = document.createElement("option");  
        opt.text= jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignName;
        opt.value = jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignId;
        //better way is
        //opt.setAttribute('value',jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignId);
        sel = document.getElementById("designBox");  
        sel.add(opt); 
        }
```

I will recommend doing it with jQuery like,

Suppose you want to attach that "ComboBox" to a Div with ID = "myCombo" (update it according to your needs)

```
var selectElement = jQuery("<select />",{id:"mySel"});

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
var optElement = jQuery("<option />",{value:jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignId,text:jsonData.DesignResult[i].DesignName);
selectElement.append(optElement);
}

$("#myCombo").append(selectElement);
```

To access the Name and ID of the selected element, use

```
var Name = $("#mySel").html();
var ID = $("#mySel").attr('value');
```

---

REMOVED OLD CODE

---

by comboBox, do you mean SELECT tag in HTML?

I am finding it hard to understand what it is that you want to do exactly?

Generate the drop down menu dynamically? or something else ?

Please give us more insight on what you want to do exactly. :)

Comment: ya i mean SELECT tag…What i meant to say is if i have DesignName in my Select then how can i get the associated DesignId on selection of that particular DesignName..I have posted JSON response also..As you can see it is having two fields as DesignName and DesignId..in short i need to show DesignName and get DesignId on selection…i have already generated drop down menu dynamically...

Comment: anybody there who can help me in that?

Comment: Updated my answer according to your needs... Take a look and let me know if you need anything :)

Comment: will the answer before your Updated answer won't work because i have tried with that and it's giving "undefined" for combo1.options[combo1.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: modified as per your code but still not working..have edited in question block..please check

Comment: 1) You have syntax error in your JSON.
2) You get JSON in string format from server (or you should) and then you need to convert that string into JavaScript JSON object. 
HINT : Use eval function for string to object conversion. :)
3) There is no such thing as jsonData.Design. (Check your JSON again.
4) Problem is not with your javascript code. Its in JSON. :)